# Can't use Control Center when UIAlertView displayed (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, control-center

So i set up a retry connection when reachability detects no connection. I want the user to be able to use the Control Center to re-enable WiFi while the UIAlertView is presented. Anyway I can do this?

[Picture Of What Control Center Looks Like](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/06/ios-control-center-2.jpg)

[Picture Of A UIAlertView](https://raw.github.com/m1entus/WCAlertView/master/Screens/1.png)

Comment: I dont believe this is possible, you have to create your own class which mimics the functionality of an AlertView. An alert seems to block all touches including system gestures. That shouldnt necessarily be the solution to your connection problem anyways (turning wifi on), what about having wireless network connection while on a iPhone?