# UIAlertView popup won't let me swipe up Control Center

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on a Xamarin MvvmCross ios app. I have it set to display a UIAlertView popup to inform the user when their internet is disabled (the app requires an internet connection).

The problem is that when this popup shows, the user can't swipe up the Control Center to activate their internet...

```
var dlg = new UIAlertView(config.Title ?? String.Empty, config.Message, null, config.CancelText, config.OkText);

dlg.Clicked += (s, e) =>
{
    var ok = (dlg.CancelButtonIndex != e.ButtonIndex);
    _activeDialog.DismissAlertDialog();
    config.OnConfirm(ok);
};

dlg.Show();
```

They then have to either click OK and race the popup reappearing, or home the app, reactivate internet, then come back to the app...

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to get around this, since UIAlertView is probably being displayed above the window that handles gestures for the Control Center. This is the way Apple made it.

I would use a custom view as a UIAlertView and fade the background view's alpha. Or you could use a library that already does this:

https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/PXAlertView

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXAlertView

**Related Questions:**

[Can't use Control Center when UIAlertView displayed (iOS 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225928/cant-use-control-center-when-uialertview-displayed-ios-7)

[UIAlertView Strange Behaviour with Shortcut Control center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854604/uialertview-strange-behaviour-with-shortcut-control-center)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response :) do you happen to know of any examples using Xamarin/C# ?